# Solve linear system of ODE's

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

It's been years since I formally saw ODE's and I am quite rusty, I don;t remember how to solve linear ODE's.

I have a problem and managed to derive the following system:

\begin{cases}
 2\ddot{q_1} = 2q_1 + q_2\\
 2\ddot{q_2} = q_1
\end{cases}

where $q_1$ and $q_2$ are scalar functions with parameter $t$.

It seems to me the solution is a trig function but I am not sure how to go about this problem.

Comment: You can exclude $q_1$ or $q_2$ and solve a scalar equation to begin with.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by excluding the terms?

Comment: Yes. From the second equation you see that $q_1'=2q_2'''$ and $q_1''=2q_2''''$. So you can replace $q_1$ and $q_1''$ in the first equation through these expressions and obtain a (fourth order) equation for $q_2$.

Comment: In the answer the same thing is done, but there $q_2$ is excluded.

Answer (score 3):

$q_2=2q_1''-2q_1$.  Then $q_2''=2q_1''''-2q_1''$. So,

$4q_1''''-4q_1''=q_1$ or $4q_1''''-4q_1''-q_1=0.$

The characteristic equation is $4r^4-4r^2-1=0$ and has four different real solutions.

$r_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2}/2}$, and $r_{3,4}=\pm\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}/2}$.

$q_2=Ae^{r_1 t}+Be^{r_2 t}+C e^{r_3 t}+D e^{r_4 t}$

From here you can derive $q_1$.